# How to set selected an option in Thymleaf and Spring

Tags: java, spring, select, thymeleaf

I have trouble when I choose an option from the dropdown list I get the information that I want but the option that I clicked doesn't stay selected.
Any ideas?

```
 <form   th:action="@{/values/fiatCurrency} "method="post">
                                <select     name="fiatCurrency" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <option id="USD"    onclick="document.getElementById(this).selected = true"  value="USD"  th:text="USD"> </option>
                                <option id="EUR"    onclick="document.getElementById(this).selected = true" value="EUR" th:text="EUR"> </option>
                                <option id="CNY"     onclick="alert( 'a ') " value="CNY"  th:text="CNY"> </option>
                                </select>
                               </form>
```

This is the Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class DataController {

  private  ApiService apiService;

public DataController(ApiService apiService) {
    this.apiService = apiService;
}

@GetMapping(value = {"/values","/values/","", "/", "/index","/cryptos"} )
public String index(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("cryptos",apiService.getCrypto(100));

    return "index";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/values/fiatCurrency")
public String choseCurrency(Model model,
                            @RequestBody  String fiatCurrency) {
    String replace=fiatCurrency.replace("fiatCurrency=","");
    model.addAttribute("cryptos", apiService.getInDifferentValues(fiatCurrency));
    return "index";
}}
```

It always returns USD value.

Comment: Why do you need document.getElementById(this).selected = true?

Comment: I wanted to set it selected= true over this but it is not working as well. That was just one thing of that what i was trying.

Comment: Use `th:value` instead of only value.

Comment: I did that but it is not helping in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending your fiatCurrency as a request parameter, instead of a request body. Spring has a powerful mechanism to map a view form to an actual object. This object will be send as `@ModelAttribute` and will be added in the model before the view is loaded.

Your form will be:

```
<form th:action="@{/values/fiatCurrency}" th:object="${fiat}" method="post">
    <select th:field="*{fiatCurrency}" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option id="USD" th:value="USD" th:text="USD"></option>
        <option id="EUR" th:value="EUR" th:text="EUR"></option>
        <option id="CNY" th:value="CNY" th:text="CNY"></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The next step is to create a class Fiat to wrap your desired data:

```
public class Fiat {

    private String fiatCurrency;

    //getters and setters
}
```

The fiat object must be added in the model before the view is provided. A simple and elegant solution is to define a new method in your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute
public void addModelAttribute(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("fiat", new Fiat());
}
```

Your post method will receive the newly created object :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/values/fiatCurrency")
public String choseCurrency(Model model,
                            @ModelAttribute Fiat fiat) {
    //..
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Thank you  for your help i was lost here with this one. This is actually my fist project on my own that i m doing.  So inside the object as `@ModelAttribute `@ModelAttribute is as well sent the information about the option that has been selected?

Comment: In `@ModelAttribute` Fiat fiat you will have access to the value of the option you've selected. When you will select EUR -> fiat.getFiatCurrency() will return EUR. You are sending only the "th:value" to the controller.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that.